# Перенос проекта из папки user/source/repos в другую

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, копирование, перенос

Есть проект Windows Forms, скопировал его из дефолтной repos в папку на рабочем столе, при открытии скопированного проекта страница, где должен отображаться макет WindowsForms(конструктор), пишется ошибка:

> Файл "E:\Users\mikkel\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Form1.cs" не поддерживает синтаксический анализ кода или его автоматическое создание, поскольку он не включен в проект с поддержкой кода.

Только что обратил внимание, что в ошибке указан старый путь к проекту, хотя Form1.cs также присутствует в скопированной папке. При открытии того же проекта из дефолтной repos такой ошибки не возникает.
Еще я заметил, что в коде программы никак не выделяется метод InitializeComponent();, хотя должен быть желтым.

Код класса Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox3.Text != "" && textBox4.Text != "" && textBox5.Text != "")

        {
            CellPhone phone = new CellPhone();
            phone.Manufacturer = textBox3.Text;
            phone.Model = textBox4.Text;
            phone.IsOld = checkBox1.Checked ? true : false;
            try
            {
                phone.Number = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
                textBox2.Text +=  $"Производитель: {phone.Manufacturer} " + Environment.NewLine + $"Модель:  {phone.Model}" + Environment.NewLine + $"Б / У:   {phone.IsOld}" + Environment.NewLine + $"Количество:  {phone.Number}" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            catch { MessageBox.Show("Кол-во указывается только цифрами."); }
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Не все поля заполнены!");
    }
}
public class CellPhone
{
    public string Manufacturer;
    public string Model;
    public int Number;
    public bool IsOld;
    public CellPhone(string manufacturer, string model, int number, bool isOld)
    {
        Manufacturer = manufacturer;
        Model = model;
        Number = number;
        IsOld = isOld;
    }
    public CellPhone() 
    {
        Manufacturer = "unknown manufacturer";
        Model = "unknown model";
        Number = 0;
        IsOld = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Мне кажется где то нужно указать новый путь до класса Form1, но я не знаю где это делается.

Comment: Не получается нормально скинуть содержание WindowsFormsApp1.csproj. Что именно там искать? Попробовал найти что-то вроде path или source но ничего подобного не нашел. А перенос я сделал просто скопировав папку с проектом в другую на рабочем столе. Кстати, программа, несмотря на ошибку, запускается без проблем и с макетом все в порядке.

Comment: По идее такой проблемы возникнуть не должно, но при условии, если код, который вы сюда выложили именно такой как в проекте. На вашем месте, я бы создал новый проект и скопировал необходимый код в него.

Comment: видимо это единственный выход, но тогда макет придется делать заново, и заново ставить имена кнопкам и проч

Comment: А как вы вообще копировали? Саму папку "WindowsFormsApp1" или иначе?

Comment: Папку, в которой sln файл и другая папка с тем же названием скопировал на рабочий стол. Может дело в кириллице в пути?

Comment: Я заметил, что наследуемый класс Form никак не выделяется в строке 
public partial class Form1 : Form, когда в рабочих проектах Form выделяется как класс. Как будто в сборку не включен сам класс Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы нашел в создании нового проекта уже в нужной папке и копированием дизайн файла и файла класса form1 в исходники